# Complete transparent drawing in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, transparent

I am drawing a circle using cocos2d, I set alpha to 0 using glColor4ub, the drawing turned into transparent, I can see a ccsprite in a layer below, that's expected.

But my question is why the drawing didn't turn into complete transparent since I set the alpha to 0 so that I cannot see the drawing but only the ccsprite below ?

If i am doing wrong , how should I fix it ?

```
- (void ) draw
{
    glLineWidth(20);
    glColor4ub(0, 255, 255, 0); //here I set alpha to 0
    ccDrawCircle( ccp(100,100), 50, 0, 50, YES);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I not sure why the circle is not completely transparent but I've had problems trying to use glColor4ub() when making cocos2d drawing calls. I would recommend replacing the
    glColor4ub(0, 255, 255, 0);
with
    ccDrawColor4B(0, 255, 255, 0);
and that should fix your problem and get the circle to be completely transparent.

Comment: But I think glColor4ub the the standard usage as showed many times in the official cocos2d example here: http://cocos2d-iphone.googlecode.com/svn-history/r802/trunk/tests/drawPrimitivesTest.m

Comment: Yeah I thought the same thing, considering that's what the cocos2d examples show. However, I've tried using glColor4ub numerous times with cocos2d drawing methods and it never seems to work. I believe the examples might have been developed with an older version of cocos2d than is currently available, and newer version requires us to use ccDrawColor4B.

Comment: ccDrawColor4B with a partial alpha (0.5) doesn't show up. I've been using ccDrawColor4F, which always shows an opaque circle.